# SQL UPDATE no errors but doesn't chage fields in the database

Tags: php, mysql

The following code runs with no errors but on the DB i still get those values=0.

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$ectoTOT=9;
$mesoTOT=1;
$endoTOT=5;  

$sql = 'UPDATE utenti2 SET ectoTOT=:ectoTOT,endoTOT=:endoTOT,mesoTOT=:mesoTOT WHERE id=:id';//:nome parametri
$rs = $db->prepare($sql);
//collego le variabili al parametro e faccio sanificazione
$rs->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindValue(':ectoTOT', $ectoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindValue(':mesoTOT', $mesoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindValue(':endoTOT', $endoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->execute();

echo 'OK';
exit;
```

Now it works... had multiple query on the same page and left **$result** instead of **$rs**

Comment: Check if `$id` has the expected value

Comment: Yes i get the right value with $id

Comment: Same value binded twice ectoTOT .and missing to bind one column endoTOT @Fetz

Comment: Seems like a "simple typographical error" to me -- just two wrong letters.  Not much value to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Same column binded value twice `ectoTOT` .And missing to bind one column `endoTOT`

```
$rs->bindValue(':ectoTOT', $ectoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Change to

```
$rs->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindValue(':ectoTOT', $ectoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindValue(':mesoTOT', $mesoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs->bindValue(':endoTOT', $endoTOT, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```